# Changing qmail's outgoing IP

Tags: linux, email, mediatemple, email-server

QMail uses the server's default IP as its outgoing IP. How do I change the IP to something else?

I tried the instructions in the following links but they don't work in my case.

1. http://www.indianwebportal.com/change-mail-server-ip-address-plesk
2. http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=99500

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How don't they work? Are there any telltale signs, particularly error messages and log files?

Comment: The email header indicates that the email was sent using the default IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm in no way an expert of qmail, but sometimes issues can be solved quite differently, specially when there're no special knobs (or they're hard to find) — you can use NAT: add iptables rule that would match outgoing TCP traffic to port 25 and SNAT it to IP you need.